# PowerShell Path Parameter Invoke-Command (UnauthorizedAccessException)

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

When running this simple script I am receiving the error message:

`+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Import-Csv], UnauthorizedAccessException`

`+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand`

---

```
Param(
[string]$Path,
[string]$Credential  
)

Invoke-Command –cn DC –Credential $Credential -ArgumentList $Path –ScriptBlock `
{import-csv -Path $args[0] | select-object –property `
@{name='Identity';expression={$_.username}},@{name='Fax';expression={$_.'fax number'}} `
| foreach{Set-ADUser -Identity $_.identity -Fax $_.fax -Confirm:$false}}
```

Any idea why this may be happening? I have correct permissions the the path that I am using.

Comment: Is that CSV file on the remote computer where the script is being invoked?  If not, you may be looking at a second-hop authentication issue.

Comment: I don't use-Credential that much, but that shouldn't be cast as a string, should it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and it was because I was not including the CSV file in my path. I was pointing to C:\Files\CSV instead of C:\Files\CSV\fax-users.csv.